# How to stop get_queried_object_id() returning child term id's also

Tags: term-meta

I use a conditional statement to display a shortcode depending on which category archive is being displayed. The issue I have is that if I use get_queried_object_id, the archive page for the parent term shows the shortcode for the parent term and the first child term.

Here's the code which returns the parent **and** the first child term shortcodes.

```php
$emk_current_term_id = get_queried_object_id();
    
// Parent Term
if ( ($emk_current_term_id==141293) || in_category(array(141293)) )     
{
    echo do_shortcode('[emk_shortcode_01]');
}
    
// Child Term
if ( ($emk_current_term_id==305) || in_category(array(305)) )
{
    echo do_shortcode('[emk_shortcode_02]');
}
```

The way I've got around this is to stipulate which result from the returned array to base the conditional statement on by using square brackets, like this.

```php
$emk_current_term_id = get_queried_object_id();
    
// Parent Term
if ( ($emk_current_term_id[0]==141293) || in_category(array(141293)) )      
{
    echo do_shortcode('[emk_shortcode_01]');
}
    
// Child Term
if ( ($emk_current_term_id[0]==305) || in_category(array(305)) )
{
    echo do_shortcode('[emk_shortcode_02]');
}
```

So each conditional statement only takes into account the first returned value in the array.

Is this the best way to return the current term id **only**, i.e., is there any way to exclude child terms from the results array for `get_queried_object_id()`.

Thanks

Comment: can you edit your question and rephrase some of the sentences? In particular this one doesn't make much sense and is confusing: _"The issue I have is that if I use get_queried_object_id, the archive page for the parent term shows the shortcode for the parent term and the first child term."_. If you can also use concrete examples of parent and child terms to make things clearer and easier to understand. Also avoid hardcoding term IDs, if those terms are accidentally deleted and recreated, or your site is migrated, none of the code will work

Comment: re-reading, are you trying to tell us that `$emk_current_term_id` is an array? What kind of URL and archive page are you using when this problem occurs? And what does `emk_shortcode_01` and `02` do? How did you test this and what are the expected and erroneous results of that test? Use the edit link under the tags to update your question. I've tried to fix the code block syntax highlighting for you and added some missing indentation

Comment: @MattK1984 Maybe you're just missing an `elseif`?.. But then, "*which result from the returned array*" - `get_queried_object_id()` returns an integer and not an array. E.g. If you're on `example.com/foo-post`, the function returns that post's ID, or if you're on `example.com/category/foo-category`, then that function returns that category's ID. Therefore you should use a function like [`is_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/), so that you're sure you're checking against a category object/ID.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue I have is that if I use get_queried_object_id, the archive
> page for the parent term shows the shortcode for the parent term and
> the first child term.

That's not what's happening. `get_queried_object_id()` will only return the ID of the current category. When you add `[0]` you're just breaking the condition check meaning that only `in_category()` is being checked. The problem is how you're using `in_category()`.

`in_category()` is supposed to be used inside the loop, and is checking the current post. When used on an archive page this is going to check the first post on the page. The reason your shortcode is being output twice is because the `get_queried_object_id()` check is `true` for the parent category, and the `in_category()` check for the child category is (apparently) true for the first post.

If you want to check which archive is being displayed get rid of `in_category()` entirely, and make sure to check `is_category()` to ensure that the queried object is a category.

```
if ( is_category() && $emk_current_term_id === 141293 ) {
    echo do_shortcode( '[emk_shortcode_02]' );
}

if ( is_category() && $emk_current_term_id === 305 ) {
    echo do_shortcode( '[emk_shortcode_02]' );
}
```

Just note that checking `is_category()` is redundant if this code is in category.php.

Answer (score 0):

the code sits inside my sidebars.php file so it's loaded on archive.php and single.php to display banners relevant to the category archive being displayed, or the category to which a single post belongs.

So if it's the Category A archive or it's a single post that belongs to Category A, show the Category A banners (which is what the shortcode does).

It's probably easier to use the following.

```
if ( is_category(141293) || ( is_single() && in_category(array(141293)) ) )
{
echo do_shortcode('[emk_shortcode_01]');
}
```

I was just trying to use the get_queried_object_id() to make sure it was definitely using the category term id for the current archive, but I guess it depends on which template the statement is loaded inside which was causing my original issue. i.e. by having in_category as part of the conditional statement without the is_single preceding it, that's what was pulling in the multiple shortcodes.

The above certainly seems to do what I need it to do.

Comment: "*it depends on which template the statement is loaded inside*" - note that the queried object (i.e. the main WordPress query that runs on page load) determines the template and not the other way round - so for example, if you're on a single Post page at `example.com/foo-post`, then [a *conditional tag* like `is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) would be true and thus WordPress loads a single post template like `single.php`.

Comment: Also, as Tom commented earlier, "*avoid hardcoding term IDs*", so you might better off use the category slug (e.g. `category-a`) instead. You could also use a variable to store the slug, e.g. `$cat_slug = 'category-a'; if ( is_category( $cat_slug ) || ( is_single() && in_category( $cat_slug ) ) )` ..